# enter key behaviour of syncfusion's Data bound grid doesn't work if any column is hidden

Tags: winforms, syncfusion

I am using Synfusion's Data Bound Grid.
I have set two properties as

```
this.mygrid.TableModel.Options.EnterKeyBehavior = GridDirectionType.Right;
this.mygrid.TableModel.Options.WrapCellBehavior = GridWrapCellBehavior.WrapGrid;
```

If no column is hidden this works fine. If i hide any column then it doesn't works.

Please help me to achieve enter key behaviour if columns are hidden.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: it would be helpful if you provide us grid control platform like asp.net, mvc, wpf, silverlight, windows etc.

Comment: @Bharath: sorry for less info. I am creating a windows application through C# and i am using Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 0):

I have handled the following code for hiding columns :

GridColHidden[] hiddenCols = new GridColHidden[ 3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)

{

hiddenCols[i] = new GridColHidden(i + 1);

}

this.gridDataBoundGrid1.Model.ColHiddenEntries.AddRange(hiddenCols);

I have now added the following code.

this.mygrid.TableModel.Options.EnterKeyBehavior = GridDirectionType.Right;
this.mygrid.TableModel.Options.WrapCellBehavior = GridWrapCellBehavior.WrapGrid;

I was able to see the first cell is set as current cell , when Enter key is pressed with the current cell's position placed in last cell in Grid.